# PL/SQL: INSERT INTO Table Based On Derived Value

Tags: oracle, plsql, toad

I want to run a SELECT Statement, Derive a Value, Then INSERT that value into a table. My Code looks something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ADDR 
  IS
  L_SQL_ERR_MSG   VARCHAR2 (250);

  CURSOR CUR_ADDRESSES
  IS         
  SELECT 
            CASE WHEN PPD.SP_ID ='11' 
                 THEN 'BILLING' 
                 WHEN PP_D.SP_ID ='157' 
                 THEN 'MAILING' 
                 ELSE NULL
                 END AS TYPE

            FROM
            SPEC_DEGREE PP_D
            WHERE PP_D.SP_ID ='11' --Currently just to extract one row
            AND PP_D.DEGREE ='DO';

 BEGIN
  FOR RCD IN CUR_ADDRESSES
  LOOP
     BEGIN
        INSERT INTO ADDITIONAL_ADDR (
                                   ID,
                                   NUM,
                                   STATE,
                                   START_DATE,
                                   TYPE)

             VALUES (
             '1',
             '12345',
             'CT',
             TO_DATE('01-01-2020', 'MM-DD-YYYY'),
             TYPE );

     EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS
        THEN
           L_SQL_ERR_MSG := SQLERRM;

           DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (SQLERRM);
     END;
  END LOOP;
END ADDR;
/
```

I know now that I cannot add columns into an insert statement but I was hoping there is a way I could add this derived value. Fairly new to PL/SQL. Any thoughts? Please let me know if you need more details.

Comment: Not clear here.  You want to insert a valued to a column that does not exist in a table? Don't you just want to create a view?

Comment: No. This needs to be loaded into a table.

Comment: So how do you expect to save a value to a table when there is no column for it?  You either have to add the column to the table, or create a view for selects that then adds the computed value.

Comment: My apologies. This is an existing table. I am inserting the values into the table ADDITIONAL_ADDR which has already been created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a cursor:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ADDR
IS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO ADDITIONAL_ADDR (
    ID,
    NUM,
    STATE,
    START_DATE,
    TYPE
  )
  SELECT '1',
         '12345',
         'CT',
         DATE '2020-01-01',
         CASE WHEN SP_ID ='11'  THEN 'BILLING' 
              WHEN SP_ID ='157' THEN 'MAILING' 
              END
  FROM   SPEC_DEGREE
  WHERE  SP_ID ='11' --Currently just to extract one row
  AND    DEGREE ='DO';
END ADDR;
/
```

Comment: Let's say I need to add more than one record. Wouldn't I need a cursor?

Comment: No, you should not need a cursor. Update your question with an example of the problem you are trying to solve and you'll get a more concrete answer.

Comment: That answers my question. Thank you.

Comment: In my experience, properly constructed "insert selects" eliminate the need for cursors. Oracle PL/SQL has a wonderful for loop that eliminates the need to create cursors unless you have some sort of dynamic SQL requirement. They also eliminate the fetch bookkeeping that you must do with cursors.